# "Pointer Expected" and "Conflicting argument type" error in C

Tags: c, pointers, compiler-errors

So, I have written a function for insertion into a queue viz `en_queue`. The function body is:

```
void en_queue(queue,max,front,rear) 
{
    int ch1;
    printf("\n Enter element to add->");
    scanf("%d",&ch1);
    if(front==0 && rear==(max-1))
    {
        printf("\n Caution!! Queue Overflow!!");
    }
    else if(rear==(max-1) && front>0)
    {
        rear=0;
        *queue[rear]=ch1;
    }
    else if(front==-1 && rear==-1)
    {
        front=rear=0;
        *queue[rear]=0;
    }
    else 
    {
        rear++;
        *queue[rear]=ch1;
    }
}
```

And the prototype declaration is:

```
void en_queue(int *,int, int, int);
```

And during calling, I called it like:

```
en_queue(queue,MAX,front,rear);
```

where `queue[MAX]` is an array (`#define MAX 10`), `MAX` is the number of elements the array can incorporate and both `front` and `rear` are integers with current value `-1`. I am getting repeated errors of `type error: pointer expected` and `Conflicting argument declarations for function 'en_queue'.`

I can't see why arguments are not matching. Because I passed an address of the array and received it in a pointer variable and worked with the pointer. So how can there be error?

Comment: Here is your problem: `*queue[rear]` Why? `queue` is of type `int *` there is no need to dereference it. Remove the `*`. Plus the error that you are getting seems to indicate that you pass `int **` type for the first argument, however the function is defined to take `int *`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First:

```
void en_queue(queue,max,front,rear) 
{
```

should be:

```
void en_queue(int *queue, int max, int front, int rear) 
{
```

And second, expressions like `*queue[rear] = 0;` should be just `queue[rear] = 0;` because `queue` is `int*`.

Note: An expression `a[i]` == `*(a + i)`, so if `a` is pointer then in expression `a[i]` you doesn't need to deference `*` explicitly.

In your expression `*queue[rear]`, you are getting error `type error: pointer expected` because you dereference twice e.g. `*queue[rear]` == `*` `*(queue + rear)` because `*(queue + rear)` is not pointer  but a int hence compiler message is need a pointer.

Compiler message: "Conflicting argument declarations for function `en_queue()`" because of first argument is `int*`. As in function definition you doesn't specify type of arguments default is considered int type.

Comment: This is same what I was thinking. Is it ok to define a function like this `void en_queue(queue,max,front,rear)` when it is already declared properly?

Comment: @nishant no we need to specify in function definition also because default is int, where as first argument is `int*`

Comment: @nishant Check this [error-code-1](http://codepad.org/Z3VLhAHv) and [code-2](http://codepad.org/3kIQrj3c)

Answer (score 3):

If `queue` is `int *` then the correct way to access it as an "array" is

```
queue[index];
```

and **NOT** `*queue[index]`

`queue[index]` is actually `*(queue + index)`.

if you do `*queue[index]` you are actually doing `*(*(queue + index))` .

`(queue + index)` will get to the address location `index` locations away from the addres stored in `queue` . `*(queue + index)` will dereference it by getting the value stored at the address. `*(*(queue + index))` will use the fetched value as an address and try to make another fetch, which is wrong because now you dereference an integer.

Answer (score 2):

While you can write a *declaration* without naming your arguments, just giving the type specifiers, you cannot write a *definition* with only the names and without the specifiers. The `conflicting argument declarations` error is because of this, because the compiler interprets the argument names in your definition as types rather than names. Think about it, how could the compiler know the difference between a name given without a type and a type given without a name?

As @grijesh has written, you should write your definition as:

```
void en_queue(int *queue, int max, int front, int rear)
```

instead.

The other problem is that you're dereferencing your pointer twice, which doesn't make sense with a pointer to an integer. An array and a pointer are similar in the way that they give a memory address that you can use to do further indexing. This can be done by using the regular index operator:

```
queue[index]
```

or using the explicit pointer dereferencing operator `*`, and pointer arithmetic like this:

```
*(queue + index)
```

Read more about pointer arithmetic [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/pointers/).

Answer (score 0):

You said: `..where queue[MAX] is an array..`

Your declaration is: `void en_queue(int *,int, int, int);`

Then what does this mean: `*queue[rear]=ch1;`

You are trying to **dereference an integer**

Correct all the instances in your program like above to: `queue[rear] = ch1;`